# Vuforia Model Target Guide View Showing Weird Position

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I am trying to test my own model target.
What I tried is that, I downloaded the Vuforia Hololens sample and changed only the database of the model target the sample scene already had. And it works perfectly as the picture below.

[image]

But On the new scene that I created, the guide view looks weird like in the picture below.

[image]

It has all the same components in the inspector.. I can't figure out what makes it show the guide view differently. Because I am using the EXACT SAME database, and I choose the same guide view option.

Does any one experienced same issue and knows solution?

I tried my model target on the Model Target Test App and it works fine!
it just doesn't show the guide view properly on the Unity Scene I created...

please help me if anyone knows about this issue..Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

to me, the mask seems to be rotated on X axis.
I would compare again the ARcamera settings in Vuforia's sample with the one in your scene, along with VuforiaConfiguration file.

At last, Vuforia might be able to help you on their github [repository](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/)